# How can I see all sent emails from my mail server?

Tags: centos, security, logs, email

My server was infected to a malware. That malware sent lots of emails to random people with random content *(promotional content)*. And now, my domain authority is getting pretty low and every email I send goes to spam.

What I said is a guess *(though I'm sure about that malware, but I'm not sure it has sent emails)*. Anyway, is there any log file or whatever similar contains a log of all emails that are sent from my mail server? If yes, where is it located?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a little more likely that hackers have found a valid username / password for your SMTP server than actually got malware onto your server.  Unless they managed to crack your root password and log in via SSH.  You should check your `/var/log/auth.log` to see if that looks likely and change any critical passwords.  Simply having a server on a domain name will cause daily brute force attacks on an SMTP and SSH attempting lots of passwords on system account names, or lots of usernames against most common passwords.

Comment: if the machine is running a web-server with an insecure formmail type CGI or php script (esp. one that allows the remote user to specify the recipient address) then that may be the source of the spam.  Martin should also check his web server logs for suspicious activity and disable any mail-sending CGI/php/etc scripts that he finds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you've configured your mail transport agent ("MTA" - e.g. postfix, sendmail, exim, etc) to save a copy of every message sent by your system, you won't have a complete copy of the messages.

MTAs do, however, log the event of every message being sent or received - minimum details logged usually include at least the sender address, recipient address, message id and/or mail queue id, and the date & time that the message was sent.

This log is usually logged via syslog to `/var/log/mail.log`.   If you're running `systemd` with syslog support disabled, you'll have to run `journalctl -u <unitname>`, where `<unitname>` is the name of your MTA's systemd unit - e.g. `postfix` or `exim` or `sendmail`.

Comment: In my case, the emails were being refused by gmail and the information was located in a file in /var/mail folder.